# Regex Pattern to match the name ending in either # or >

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have been trying to find a single regex pattern that will help me to match 4 different kind of cases from where I can retrieve the Hostname.

Case 1: HOSTNAME#
Case 2: HOSTNAME>
Case 3: myid8@HOSTNAME>
Case 4: myid8@HOSTNAME#

For all the cases above I need to match only the Hostname, the Hostname can be anything;

so far I have tried to match
"#" for case 1,
">" for case 2,
trying to match the first "@" and ">" for case 3
and "@" and "#" for case 4.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
def testingregex(self):
    if "@" in self.device_name:
        m = re.search(r'@(.*)>|@(.*)#', self.device_name)
        print("Hostname on the Device is: %s" % m.group(1))
    else:
        m = re.search(r'^(.+?)#|^(.+?)>', self.device_name)
        try:
            print("Hostname on the Device is: %s" % m.group(1))
        except:
            print("Hostname on the Device is: %s" % m.group(2))
```

My file has all the four kinds of cases:
I get this output:
HOSTNAME
None
HOSTNAME
None

Comment: Hostname can be anything including spaces?

Comment: It won't have any white space, but it can have "-", numbers, or any other character possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
[^@ ]+(?=[#>])
```

`[^@ ]+` finds the hostname by excluding `@` or a space in it capturing one or more characters and stops capturing when it makes sure it is followed by `#` or `>` using positive look ahead `(?=[#>])`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ck1PbY/1)**

Sample Python codes,

```
import re

arr = ['HOSTNAME#','HOSTNAME>','myid8@HOSTNAME>', 'myid8@HOSTNAME#']

for s in arr:
 m = re.search(r'[^@ ]+(?=[#>])', s)
 if (m):
  print(s, ' --> ', m.group())
```

Prints,

```
HOSTNAME#  -->  HOSTNAME
HOSTNAME>  -->  HOSTNAME
myid8@HOSTNAME>  -->  HOSTNAME
myid8@HOSTNAME#  -->  HOSTNAME
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex using negative character class and a lookahead:

```
[^#>@]+(?=[#>]$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/O2jGrn/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `[^#>@]+`: Match 1+ characters that are not `#` and `>` and `@`
- `(?=[#>]$)`: Lookahead to assert we have `#` or `>` before end of line.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to optionally match what is before the hostname including the `@` and then capture the hostname in a capture group:

```
(?:\S+@)?(\S+)[#>]
```

That will match:

- `(?:\S+@)?` Optional non capturing group which matches 1+ times a non-whitespace character followed by an @
- `(\S+)` Capture group that matches 1+ non-whitespace characters
- `[#>]` Character class, match of # or >

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ns1aAG/1/) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9r0hNN)